# Office365 Outlook REST API Does Not Return All Messages

Tags: rest, powershell, outlook, office365, outlook-restapi

I am using Office365 and trying to get message count in Mail Folders with the following Powershell command:

```
( Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -Uri ("https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/me//Messages/") -Credential $UserCredential ).Count
```

Mailbox I am using has 598 messages total however the command above will return only 10

If I take another approach and use the following command I would get 266 messages:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -Uri ("https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/me//Messages/`$count") -Credential $UserCredential
```

Is there any way to get all the messages recursively in Office365 using REST API and if so, what I am doing wrong?

Kind regards

Yuriy

Comment: you could try to iterate the nextLink to get all the messages

Answer (score 2):

API `me/messages` will not return all the messages at one time, the default length is 10.

To get all the messages, you can use [$top and $skip](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398165).

For example: `me/Messages?$top=20` will get the top 20 messages, `me/Messages?$skip=20&$top=20` will get the next 20 messages.

Comment: That is great, thank you so much. Is there a way to get messages across all folders recursively? In addition, where can I find all parameters accepted on Office365 via REST API?  I don't seem to find top and skip anywhere in MSDN.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: It does seem the best I can get for $top is 500. But what if I need to process 7000+ messages?

Comment: @Yuriy, in this case, you can use $skip to get the next 500 messages, for example, if you have 1500 messages, you can request 3 times. $skip and $top are odata URI conversions. I will update my answer to add the odata document

Comment: no longer true. At least with my account, there are only 60 messages I can get using $top and $skip